# Use IP column of 2 dataframes and date range to populate df1 dataframe with data from df2

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with 2 dataframes.  The first has incomplete information.  The second dataframe has information with a time range of first seen and last seen.  I am trying to use the source address and the time range from df2 to fill in the sourcehostname and sourceusername where datetime from df1 falls into that time range.

```
df1
        sourceaddress   sourcehostname  sourceusername  endtime         datetime
0       10.0.0.59       computer1       NaN             1564666638000   2019-08-01 09:37:18
1       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666640000   2019-08-01 09:37:20
2       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666642000   2019-08-01 09:37:22
3       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666643000   2019-08-01 09:37:23
4       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666643000   2019-08-01 09:37:23
5       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666645000   2019-08-01 09:37:25
6       10.0.0.59       computer1       NaN             1564666646000   2019-08-01 09:37:26
7       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666646000   2019-08-01 09:37:26
8       10.0.0.59       computer1       NaN             1564666649000   2019-08-01 09:37:29
9       10.0.0.59       computer1       NaN             1564666650000   2019-08-01 09:37:30
10      10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666850000   2019-08-01 09:40:50
...
43196   10.0.0.187      computer2       NaN             1564718395000   2019-08-01 23:59:55
43197   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718397000   2019-08-01 23:59:57
43198   10.0.0.187      computer2       NaN             1564718397000   2019-08-01 23:59:57
43199   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718398000   2019-08-01 23:59:58
43200   10.0.0.187      NaN             NaN             1564718398000   2019-08-01 23:59:58
43201   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718398000   2019-08-01 23:59:58

df2
        sourceaddress   sourcehostname  sourceusername  firstseen             lastseen
0       10.0.0.59       computer1       user1           2019-08-01 09:37:59   2019-08-01 09:46:08
1       10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           2019-08-01 00:00:03   2019-08-01 23:59:58
```

Desired Result:

```
df3
        sourceaddress   sourcehostname  sourceusername  endtime         datetime
0       10.0.0.59       computer1       NaN             1564666638000   2019-08-01 09:37:18
1       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666640000   2019-08-01 09:37:20
2       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666642000   2019-08-01 09:37:22
3       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666643000   2019-08-01 09:37:23
4       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666643000   2019-08-01 09:37:23
5       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666645000   2019-08-01 09:37:25
6       10.0.0.59       computer1       NaN             1564666646000   2019-08-01 09:37:26
7       10.0.0.59       NaN             NaN             1564666646000   2019-08-01 09:37:26
8       10.0.0.59       computer1       NaN             1564666649000   2019-08-01 09:37:29
9       10.0.0.59       computer1       NaN             1564666650000   2019-08-01 09:37:30
10      10.0.0.59       computer1       user1           1564668650000   2019-08-01 10:10:50
...
43196   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718395000   2019-08-01 23:59:55
43197   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718397000   2019-08-01 23:59:57
43198   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718397000   2019-08-01 23:59:57
43199   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718398000   2019-08-01 23:59:58
43200   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718398000   2019-08-01 23:59:58
43201   10.0.0.187      computer2       user1           1564718398000   2019-08-01 23:59:58
```

**following the example from below:

```
df3[-5:]
        sourceaddress   sourcehostname  sourceusername  endtime          datetime               firstseen              lastseen
43197   10.99.0.187     computer2       user1           1564718397000    2019-08-01 23:59:57    2019-08-01 00:00:03    2019-08-01 23:59:58
43198   10.99.0.187     computer2       NaN             1564718397000    2019-08-01 23:59:57    2019-08-01 00:00:03    2019-08-01 23:59:58
43199   10.99.0.187     computer2       NaN             1564718398000    2019-08-01 23:59:58    2019-08-01 00:00:03    2019-08-01 23:59:58
43200   10.99.0.187     computer2       user1           1564718398000    2019-08-01 23:59:58    2019-08-01 00:00:03    2019-08-01 23:59:58
43201   10.99.0.187     computer2       user1           1564718398000    2019-08-01 23:59:58    2019-08-01 00:00:03    2019-08-01 23:59:58
```

Comment: how long are your `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: df1 is about 80 million rows with a few thousand  users and computers.  df2 is about a few thousand.

Comment: In your sample, `df2.sourceaddress` doesn't match `df1.sourceaddress`, is it intentional?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I fixed it @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a `merge` problem:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,
                on='sourceaddress', how='left',
                suffixes=['','_df2']
               )
# mark the valid time:
mask = df3['datetime'].ge(df3['firstseen']) & df3['datetime'].lt(df3['lastseen'])

# update the info
df3.loc[mask, 'sourcehostname'] = df3.loc[mask, 'sourcehostname_df2']
df3.loc[mask, 'sourceusername'] = df3.loc[mask, 'sourceusername_df2']
```

And then you can drop `sourcehostname_df2` and `sourceusername_df2`.

Comment: I followed your example and have posted the results to the end of my question.  I even dropped the two field with ..._df2 after.  I am still not getting the username to as user1 in the column.  It should be there because it falls into the time frame.

Comment: I can see one row coming from `lt(df3['lastseen'])`, change it to `le(df3['lastseen'])`.

Comment: Yep, changing it from less than to less or equal to worked.  Thank you for helping me @Quang Hoang